# Use a Login form with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I know there are very similar posts to this on Stackoverflow but I still can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my attempt.

```
# login to the site 
mech.get(base_URL) do |page|
  l = page.form_with(:action => "/site/login/") do |f|
    username_field = f.field_with(:name => "LoginForm[username]")
    username_field.value = userName
    password_field = f.field_with(:name => "LoginForm[password]")
    password_field.value = password
    f.submit
  end
end
```

Here is my error:

```
rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `field_with' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="bucketbody">

    <div class="form padding10">
    <form id="login-form" action="/site/login" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="note float_right">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
            <label for="LoginForm_username" class="required">Email address <span class="required">*</span></label>              <input class="width_66per" autofocus="" name="LoginForm[username]" id="LoginForm_username" type="text">                         </div>

        <div class="row">
            <label for="LoginForm_password" class="required">Password <span class="required">*</span></label>               <input class="width_66per" name="LoginForm[password]" id="LoginForm_password" type="password">                          </div>

                    <div class="row rememberMe nolabel">
            <span class="field"><input id="ytLoginForm_rememberMe" value="0" name="LoginForm[rememberMe]" type="hidden"><input name="LoginForm[rememberMe]" id="LoginForm_rememberMe" value="1" type="checkbox">                <label for="LoginForm_rememberMe">Remember me on this computer</label>                              </span>
        </div>

        <p class="note"><a href="http://test.XXXXXXXX.com/user/reset">Forgot your password?</a></p>

        <div class="row buttons" style="padding-left: 0px;">
            <input class="pushButton" name="yt0" value="Login" type="submit">           </div>

    </form>     </div><!-- form -->

</div>
```

p page

```
#<Mechanize::Page
 {url #<URI::HTTP:0x225ce70 URL:http://xxxxxx.com/>}
 {meta_refresh}
 {title "xxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxx"}
 {iframes}
 {frames}
 {links
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "\r\n                        " "/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "About xxxxxx" "/features">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "xxxxx Overview" "/features">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "xxxxxxx for Associations" "/associations">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "xxxxxx For Education" "/education">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "FAQ" "/faq">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "About Us" "/aboutus">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "About Us" "/aboutus">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "News & Events" "/news-events">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Environmental Commitment" "/environment">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Our Team" "/ourteam">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "The xxxxxxxxxx" "/xxxxxxxxxx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Free Trial" "/freetrial">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Contact" "/contacts">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Contact us" "/contacts">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "xxxxxxxxxx"
   "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/services/web-services/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "inquire@xxxxxxxxx.com"
   "mailto:inquire@xxxxxxxxxxx.com">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link xxxxxx" "http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Technology Association of Oregon"
   "http://www.techoregon.org/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "http://www.terrapass.com/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "http://www.arborday.org/">}
 {forms}>
```

Comment: Ruby is telling you that `f` is `nil`, so probably no form was found. Can we please see the HTML for the form?

Comment: I think you should write `f.submit` instead of `form.submit`

Comment: @padde changed the f.submit

Answer (score 5):

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be:

```
page = mech.get base_URL

form = page.form # page.forms[1], etc.
form['LoginForm[username]'] = userName
form['LoginForm[password]'] = password

l = form.submit form.button
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you send the post request directly? Try this:

```
respond = mech.post('www.mysite.com/site/login', "LoginForm[username]" => userName,    "LoginForm[password]" => password)
```

If you know the target (/site/login), the request method (post), and the params you must send, do the post request without messing with the form.

Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mech.get(base_URL) do |page|
  l = page.form_with(:action => "/site/login") do |f|
    username_field = f.field_with(:name => "LoginForm[username]")
    username_field.value = userName
    password_field = f.field_with(:name => "LoginForm[password]")
    password_field.value = password
  end.submit
end
```

i dropped the `/` at the end of `:action => "/site/login/"` and chained `submit` directly after the block, as in the [mechanize example page](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html). I did not run the code though, so let me know if it works.

Comment: Please inspect `page` by inserting `p page` before the line `l = page.form_with #...` and post the output here.

Comment: Ok there it is, let me know if you need more info

Comment: Well the last line (`{forms}`) tells you that there are no forms on the page. Try `curl` in order to check if you get the response from the webserver that you are expecting (i.e. containing the form).

Comment: Ok I really don't understand this,  When I do this in IRB I see a difernet output

Comment: could It not be following a redirect

Comment: Does it have a form? Something like `{forms
  #<Mechanize::Form
...}`

Comment: Very strange. Are you running this inside an app that uses bundler or so? Just checking that you use the same gem version in your script and IRB... If in doubt, `puts Mechanize::VERSION` in both script and IRB

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24728/discussion-between-padde-and-zach)

Comment: It looks like it is following a redirect in IRB get('http://xxxx.com') goes to URL:http://xxxx.com/site/login