# Clicking multiple submit buttons with mechanize

Tags: ruby, forms, button, mechanize, dropdown

I'm working on a script with mechanize in Ruby. I'm trying to select the values of the form(dropdown), however the values for the second field of the form don't appear until the first field has a selection. It prevents the following -

```
my_form[0].options[2].select
my_form[1].options[2].select
my_form[2].options[2].select
my_form[3].options[0].select
```

because the second field doesn't have any value at this point. The selection of the first part works like it should, however.

The line in the form looks like this

```
<select id="DistrictId" name="DistrictId"><option value="">---SELECT---</option>
<option value="3">Alaska Gateway School District</option>
...
</select>
<input type="button" id="selectDistrict" value="SELECT">
```

I see there is a Select button after the field, however I'm not sure on how to click it and have the second field populate.

When I use the following

```
my_form.button_with(:value => "SELECT").click
```

I don't get an error, but it also doesn't repopulate the second field. I tried placing that line after the selection of the first field, and it gets me no further.

I haven't seen anything that is super helpful with dropdown menus.

[Use a Login form with Mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945299/use-a-login-form-with-mechanize) was helpful in dealing with the form, but didn't help with actually selecting that button.

The other thing that I need this to do is to loop though all of the options in the drop down menus.

I've been able to find some things about dropdowns and python, which has also helped.

I can select the part with the

```
.options[x]
```

But I am unsure as to how to know when to end the looping. It looks like the elements are stored as an array, and so I can just do .each do on the forms. http://crabonature.pl/posts/23-automation-with-mechanize-and-ruby was helpful for going through the form, but it all comes back to having to select the top form value before being able to see the values in the fields under it.

Comment: I do not believe you will be able to use Mechanize. Mechanize does not process JavaScript, which is why clicking the button does nothing.

Comment: You're probably going to have to set it like this: `form[field_name] = value`